# Can't rename each 'file' to 'file.text' (using xargs)

Tags: command-line, files, rename, mv, xargs

I have received a task to do these commands on a text file:

1. Choose each second field from the file
2. Sort and choose first 3 unique `value`s
3. Print the contents of each `value.text` while redirecting stderr

The thing I've come with is

```
cut cities.txt -f1 | sort| uniq | head -3 | xargs rename "s/*/*.text/" * | xargs cat 2>error.txt
```

but this gives an error:

```
Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/* <-- HERE / at (user-supplied code).
```

I also tried to do it with `mv * *.text`, but it doesn't work, saying `mv: target 'Germany' is not a directory`, with "Germany" being the last value in the list of `value`s.

Either of these commands is fine with me, but explaining why both of them do not work (and how to make them work) would be more appreciated.

Comment: Replace `rename "s/*/*.text/"` with `rename 's/.*/$&.txt/'`

Comment: We can't help you parse a file you're not showing us. Please [edit] your question and show us a a few representative lines of your file, and the output you expect from it. Also explain how fields are defined (spaces? tabs? commas? something else?).

Comment: Well,  in case it isn't obvious, I should specify it: original file includes country-city names and I need to take the country names, the delimiter doesn't matter - my code finds the correct values, then sort and take first 3 unique values, which outputs as "Austria France Germany" with each word on a new line. Then I should try to print the content of Austria.text, France.text and Germany.text

Comment: AlexF, if you want to get a good answer to your question, don't merely "describe" your file.  Do what @terdon suggested and include sample lines in your question.  Do this by clicking on [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/958768/edit).

Comment: No, it isn't obvious. And your code makes no sense so it doesn't help us understand. Please edit as I asked so that we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone ever stumbles upon this question: John1024's comment to the question is the correct solution, though there's one thing to notice - the error messages generated by the attempt to print out the contents of non-existing files are generated by `xargs rename "s/.*/$&.text/"`, therefore if you need to redirect your error messages to a different file, you have to append `2>error.text` to the `rename` command, and not write another one `| xargs cat 2>error.txt`